# How to convert a multiple line input into single/multiple line output | BASH

Tags: bash, shell

What I really want

Input:

```
<int> 
45
</int>
<string>
Name
</string>
```

output:

```
<int> 45 </int>
<string> Name </string>
```

Here is what I've come up w/ so far(needs tweaking) for the desired output above:

```
printf "please enter some values \n"
readarray -t arr 

echo "" ${arr[@]} && cat >> input.txt
```

my output: `<int> 45 </int> <string> Name </string>`

Comment: Can you edit your question and explain exactly what you want. Are you giving the input on the commandline or is it a file? You show 2 different output's. Do you want the first? You create an output file called input. Why are you using an array, do you need that later?

Comment: Edited, please see if you can help @WalterA. I'm using the txt file so that, the input does not get printed as elements of an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `printf`

```
$ printf '%s %s %s\n' $(cat input.txt)
<int> 45 </int>
<string> Name </string>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to combine each 3 lines, you can use

```
cat inputfile | paste -d " " - - -
```

When you can have values with more than one line, you might use

```
tr -d '\n' < inputfile | sed 's#</[^>]*>#&\n#g'
```

Or with `awk` :

```
awk '/<\/.*>/ {print; next} {printf $0}' inputfile
```